# How to install only the sass version of bootstrap via NPM but NOT the JS

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I am working on a project where we want to use bootstrap's CSS (via sass) but not the JS. I have not problem including bootstrap-sass via NPM, but I don't want all the JS files along with the sass files as we have no use for them.

I have looked for an NPM package that is just the sass part of bootstrap without the js, but have not been successful.

Assuming there is not a package, is there a way in NPM to install just part of a package? If so, I would appreciate instructions on doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot install just a part of the package with `npm`. You could host your own fork of Bootstrap, for example on [GitHub](https://github.com) that contains only the `scss` folder and install that with `npm` though.

1. Fork the repo https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass or (v4 at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev)
2. Remove everything you don't need (not the style files, not the `package.json`...)
3. Install it via `npm`

   `npm install yourusernameatgithub/bootstrap-sass --save`

   (or the v4)

   `npm install yourusernameatgithub/bootstrap#v4-dev --save`

However the JavaScript (and other files) shouldn't matter unless you don't have some kind of a build system in place (which considering you are using `npm` you probably should) or you are very restrained with either disk base or bandwidth. The whole repo weights around 5 megabytes, the `npm` version around ~1.75 megabytes. So essentially you would be saving only around ~1.5 megabytes of disk space / bandwidth per installation at best.

Comment: What I gather is that while I can easily fork and install, there is not a real reason to do so? I just didn't want the js files at all, we are building using gulp. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacques exactly. The only thing you lose is fraction of disk space and bandwidth, the extra effort of maintaining your own fork is most likely much harder than just avoiding the files on disk :)

Comment: Sounds like I'll not worry about it then. :)